# GCP Cloud Functions - Stateful Saving

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, stateless, stateful, saving-data

I have `GCP` Math `FaaS`s, as well as an intermediary `Proxy` FaaS.

I would like the Proxy to save the answer to a `database`, containing an ID and Value.

I understand `Cloud` functions are supposedly `Stateless`. How do I go about this?

Update: I am following along with this https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions

Will let you know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

You can use statefull services: Cloud SQL or Datastore/Firestore.

All depends the number of read/write and the query complexity that you want to achieve. Have a close look to the pricing and to the query limitation of Firestore and Datastore. If you still have doubt, don't hesitate to add detail, your existing code, errors,....